# On Clarifai API, does the general models have static concept IDs?

Tags: clarifai

When getting the list of concepts of "general-v1.3" model using the API using the following request

```
curl -X GET \
https://api.clarifai.com/v2/models/aaa03c23b3724a16a56b629203edc62c/output_info \
-H 'authorization: Key xxx-api-key-xxx'
```

I'm getting the listing of all the available outputs of the model with this format:

```
{
  ...
  "model": {
    "aaa03c23b3724a16a56b629203edc62c",
    "name": "general-v1.3",
    "created_at": "2016-03-09T17:11:39.608845Z",
    "app_id": "main",
    "output_info": {
      "data": {
        "concepts": [
          {
            "id": "ai_jH6mzv12",
            "name": "Adriatic",
            "created_at": "2016-03-17T11:43:01.223962Z",
            "language": "en",
            "app_id": "main",
            "definition": "an arm of the Mediterranean between Slovenia and Croatia and Montenegro and Albania on the east and Italy on the west"
          },
          ...
```

Every concepts has an id. Considering the "general" model gets an update to a v1.4 for example, I guess it will get a new model_id but will those concept IDs change?

Answer (score 2):

Eddie from Clarifai here.

Concept id's will **not** be remapped to different concept values for a **specific model**. Meaning that (from your snippet) the concept with the id of `ai_jH6mzv12` will always have the value `Adriatic` for the **general model**.

When the model version changes the concepts associated with the model are subject to change but the concept id's will not.

If you want total locked in consistency you can use a specific model version in the URL but keep in mind you will not get model improvements unless you bump the pinned version.

```
https://api.clarifai.com/v2/models/aaa03c23b3724a16a56b629203edc62c/versions/aa9ca48295b37401f8af92ad1af0d91d/output_info
```

Also worth mentioning that the model name `general-v1.3` is somewhat misleading as every time the model is retrained a new model version is created and the major version should be technically bumped.

Hope this helps! Check the [docs](https://clarifai.com/developer/guide/) for more.